# How to wrap custom endpoints in Django Tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

I want to add a dispatch method to some resource so I could use a wrapper decorator on it.
The issue is that it only works on the CRUD operations and wont go into the dispatch method on 'original' endpoints:

```
class SomeResource(SomeBaseResource):
    class Meta(...): ...
    
    def get_something_extra(self, request, **kwargs):
        ...

    def patch_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        ...
```

and the base resource:

```
class SomeBaseResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta(...): ...
    
    # the wrapper
    @decorator_to_wrap_all_methods_with(...)
    def dispatch(self, request_type, request, **kwargs):
         logger.info('Enter')
         response = super(SomeBaseResource, self).dispatch(request_type, request, **kwargs)
         logger.info('Exit')
         return response
```

So when I use patch request it is working as expected, but wont on calling the get_something_extra api.

How do I wrap ALL methods in resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround solution is to add Middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = (
'my.basic.BaseMiddleware',
...
)

class BaseMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    @decorator_to_wrap_all_methods_with(...)
    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```